# How to get current date - 5 in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, date

I am trying to get date which is 5 days from today, my code snippet looks like this -

```
Date curDate = new Date();
out.println(curDate);
String pattern = "yyyy.MM.dd";

DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
//String DateToStr = format1.format(curDate);
String DateToStr = format1.format(curDate);
out.println(DateToStr);

Date date = format1.parse(DateToStr);
Date prevdate = DateUtils.addDays(Date(), -5);
```

Though getting the current date 2016.02.19, i am not able to nail 5 days before which is 2016.02.14.

Any suggestions what's that i am doing wrong here? Or any better way to do this?
Appreciate your help.

Arun

Comment: Does it even compile? I miss `new` on the last line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  java.text. SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -5); //  5 days back date
String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(output);
  }
}
```

Comment: **output : 14/02/2016**

This is a simple java program.You can use this logic in your jsp page to get your desired output